# CSS Positioning: How to make 2 overlapping divs and then 1 more div to the right of the overlapping divs

Tags: html, css

How do I position 2 divs that overlap plus a third div just to the right of those overlapping divs (but the third not floated all the way right)?

```
<div id=one>I overlap id=two.</div>

<div id=two>I overlap id=one.</div>

<div id=three>I am just to the right of one and two.</div>
```

The desired layout is:

**| one-overlaps-two | three |**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4syjS.png

I know I can overlap the first 2 divs using a wrapper div that's `position:relative` and setting divs one & two to `position:absolute`

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id=one>I overlap id=two.</div>

    <div id=two>I overlap id=one.</div>

</div>

#wrapper{position:relative;}
#one,#two{position:absolute;}
```

But how can I get div id=three just to the right of overlapping divs one & two?

What I've got so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/justAsking/cXrBA/

Comment: Please put you code into http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: can you draw a diagram in paint??

Comment: @EdHeal Here's a jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/justAsking/cXrBA/ Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @SaurabhLP  I don't have enough reputation to post an image :-(  But here's a link:  http://i.imgur.com/4CMNaUh.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution can be as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/cXrBA/2/

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper {
    padding-left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.one , .two {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.one {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.two {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
}
.three {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks...this works! Do I understand correctly that absolutely positioned elements are taken out of document flow so I will always have to hard-code the wrapper width to get my desired alignment? Or is there another way to get the desired alignment without hard-coding widths?

Comment: No, the hard-coding of the wrapper width is not mandatory. I have done hard-coding just for illustrative purpose. You can remove the `width` property from `.wrapper` and `.three`, so that the third div takes available width-space.

Answer (score 0):

Give the second div a negative margin-left;

http://jsfiddle.net/HXH76/

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}

#one {
    background: hsla(0,100%, 50%, 0.50);
}

#two {
    background: hsla(90,100%, 50%, 0.50);
    margin-left: -40px;    
}

#three {
    background: hsla(180,100%, 50%, 0.50);
}
```

Comment: So display:inline-block for all three divs and then use margin-left to move div-two on top of div-one?  I see you hard-coded -40px. How can I set margin-left without hard-coding the number of pixels?

Comment: Well how much do you want it to cover it up? What will determine that?

Comment: #one & #two are the same size (they overlap exactly). I would like #three to be just to the right of #one+#two (but #three does not overlap #one+#two.